# How many squares can form an arithmetic progression?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-progressions, perfect-squares

Related to this question : [Find three arithmetic progressions of three square numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470895/find-three-arithmetic-progressions-of-three-square-numbers)

I am looking for a sequence $$a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n$$ forming an arithmetic progression such that all the $a_j$ are perfect squares, an example with $3$ entries is $$49,169,289$$ However, the next term would be $409$ , not being a perfect square.

> Can the index $n$ be aqrbitary large ? In other words, can the sequence be arbitary long ? If not, what is the maximum possible value for $n$ ?

Comment: No, there can't be more than three squares in arithmetic progression. This question has been asked, and answered, several times on this website. Let's try to find it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What is the main idea to prove that $3$ is the maximum ?